# Upload video to Twitter using Twitter API

Tags: java, video, twitter, upload

I'm using Twitter API to upload a video , so , following to Twitter API Documentation for chunked_video_upload , I have implemented the 3 steps mentionned here (calling end-points from java code )[INIT => APPEND => FINALIZE][1] [1]: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media.html , but they didn't declare how to set access token before using the 3 steps , because we have to set the user Access Token to upload a video on behalf of his account .

Thanks .

Comment: The documentation uses `twurl`- Twitter's command line tool see [here](https://github.com/twitter/twurl).

Comment: Yes, but this twurl tool need ruby  and i'm building an app using Java . thanks

Comment: Does it fails when u sent Auth tokens in header?

Comment: What is the name and the value format of Auth parameter to add it to the request header/body ?

Comment: [This](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests) will shed some light!

Comment: ok , this is helpful , Thanks